# Adding/Deleting Rows from DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I've been trying to add and remove rows from a DataTable in a Gridview. Surpisingly adding works with one exception, it draws the table all over again every time (here is most probably the issue with the rest I want). When I try to remove a row I keep having the message that so many rows don't exists. But `dt.rows.count` give truly a value.

I think when the function is called it start all the time over again from nothing. I checked this when I place some values in the cells and added a row. And yes it draws everything all over again. So I think I have to start all over again and I'm a bit lost on how to tackle this issue.

I'll try to show the code I have at the moment:

```
private void tbxMachineTotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Create data table for the amount of machines at particular site


DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Machine Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Serial No");
dt.Columns.Add("Type No");
dt.Columns.Add("Type");
dt.Columns.Add("Purpose");
dt.Columns.Add("Nom Speed (rpm)");
dt.Columns.Add("Freq (Hz)");
dt.Columns.Add("Nom power (kW)");

int count = Convert.ToInt32(txbMachineTotal.Text);
int TotalDelta = count - MachineTotal;

    if (TotalDelta == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
    else if (TotalDelta > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
    else if (TotalDelta < 0)
    {
    TotalDelta = (TotalDelta * -1);
         for (int i = 1 ; i <= TotalDelta ; i++)
         {
         //var row = dt.NewRow();
         dt.Rows[i].Delete() ;
         }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
MachineTotal = Convert.ToInt32(txbMachineTotal.Text);
label5.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows.Count);
}
```

So my question is how does one create a DataTable and append it to the gridview and then when you want to add or remove e.g. the last 2 rows this works such dat the rest of your data doesn't get lost.
I assume I need to avoid the whole table will be drawn over again. But that I don't know how to do.

The plan is basically to create a kind of template with data which I want to parse to a XML file. So I can save it and store it and open it later for further things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have to ask… “why” is the code “creating” a NEW `DataTable` every time the text boxes text changes? If you simply want to add some rows to the “existing” `DataTable`, then simply do not create a new one as your code currently does. I am just saying that if your code "creates" a NEW table and then sets it as the `DataSource` to the grid... then... obviously it will have to redraw the grid. Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Well simple because I don't know how to fix that easily. Would I have to declare that in the Class instead of the function. Or maybe I miss something here ;). Reading your answer I probably make a silly mistake and do not understand it fully. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: I am only trying to help and mean no disrespect, but I have read your question several times and I still do not know what you are asking or what you want to do. First, keep this simple for us… the posted code is a text box’s `TextChanged` event. So, the text in the text box changes and the event fires… “what” do you want to happen? The code appears to “create” a new `DataTable`, add some columns, then uses some strange logic to add or remove rows from the newly created table `dt` then sets the grids `DataSource` to the table `dt` … ? …

Comment: In a general sense, what do want to happen when the text changes in the text box. I also assume you may not be aware that the text boxes `TextChanged` event fires whenever the user “types” a “single” character and I am betting you want to wait until the user is done typing BEFORE you run your code. I am guessing you want to run the code when the user leaves the text box… Or some other mechanism for the user to say _“OK the text is NOW changed”_ … like a button.